# PHP operator <>

Tags: php, comparison, operators

What does the following code do? A link to something in the PHP manual would also be nice.

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] <> 443) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Same as !=, "Not equal"

```
false <> true // operator will evaluate expression as true
false != true // operator will evaluate expression as true
```

Here is some reference: [PHP Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/operators.comparison)

Answer (score 7):

It's another way of saying "not equal to" (the `!=` operator). I think of it as the "less than or greater than" operator which really just means "not equal to".

Comment: It is equivalent to saying: Less than AND greater than.

Comment: @RobFarr I don't think so. Nothing can be less than and greater than.

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to `!=`:

http://au.php.net/operators.comparison

​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` gets the port used by the web server to serve HTTP requests. `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] <> 443` checks if the port is not equal to 443 (the default HTTPS port) and if not, invokes `doSomething()`

Answer (score 2):

Note that `<>` behaves as `!=` even where `<` and `>` are not obvious comparison operators (eg `$str1 <> $str2`).

Comment: Why < and > are not "obvious comparison operators" for strings?

Comment: What the hell do they compare? As far as I can tell, they compare the "value" (alphabetically, a < b) of the strings. I can't imagine a use case for that.

Comment: @PhiLho Strings are not often thought of as less than or greater than each other, unless you're comparing the length of the string. This is where most of the confusion arises.

Comment: @orokusaki: Really? I wonder how you sort strings then...

Comment: @PhiLho I'm speaking in respects to comparison operators, not sorting algorithms.

Comment: @orokusaki: well, AFAIK, sorting algorithms use comparison operators...

Comment: @orokusaki: Perhaps we are not talking of the same thing. The code: s1 = "Absolute"
s2 = "Bazaar"
print(s1 < s2)
print(s1 == s2)
print(s1 > s2)
shows true, false, false in Lua, Python and with minor changes PHP, JavaScript and probably lot of other languages.

Comment: I think it comes from Delphi/Pascal. Actually I can see a lot of Delphi/Pascal solutions in PHP like function declarations, ord(), chr() "and" "or" logic operators etc. It seems to me PHP is 50% C and 50% Pascal.

Answer (score 2):

Although PHP is mostly based on C-style syntax, this is one of the weird things that comes from the BASIC-style syntax world.

Needless to say, I'd just use `!=` and be consistent with it, as `<>` is really never used.